# Is there a way to consume all of the file descriptors of a running proc?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, file-descriptor

it is a negative testing to check if the program could handle the FD exhausting issue, and I am not able to modify the code. I need to check how the problem behave when hit the limit. it at least not being allowed to crash

I want to consume all the FDs of a running process, I tried the followed command to reduce the softlimit and hardlimit of the process to simulate this, however, I want to real consume the opened FD to its original limit, is there any other ways to achieve this?

```
# ls /proc/169607/fd|wc -l
503
# prlimit --pid 169607 --nofile=503:503
```

I also have other follow up questions need to confirm, I tried to attach the process in gdb and invoke open to consume the FD, it works like in below:

```
# this way works
(gdb) p open("/dev/null")
$11 = 80
# shell does not work
(gdb) shell for i in `seq 1 10`; do echo $i>"/dev/null"; done 
$1 = 5
(gdb) define lopen
Type commands for definition of "lopen".
End with a line saying just "end".
>set $total = $arg0
>set $i = 0
>   while($i<$total)
 >     set $i = $i + 1
 >     p open("/dev/null")
 >  end
>end
(gdb) lopen 10 # this works in loop
```

I found I could still open files even if reached the hard limit and soft limit of the current consumed amount, why is that?

E.g.,

```
# ls /proc/169607/fd|wc -l
503
# prlimit --pid 169607 --nofile=503:503
# In gdb I could still open files, and I found the fd keep increasing
(gdb) p open("/dev/null")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details and background information. What's the use case for this? What do you want to achieve? Do you want to make a program fail because the limit of open file descriptors is reached? Can you modify the source code of the program? Can you run it from a wrapper program that will use lots of file descriptors before startign your program?

Comment: Attach a debugger to the process and start issuing a lot of `open()` on stuff like `/dev/null`.

Comment: Write a wrapper program that uses `open` or `dup` to consume a user-defined number of file descriptors first, and then uses `execvp` or similar to run your program.

Comment: You can also use an `LD_PRELOAD` library to replace `open()` etc. with wrappers that return an error instead of calling the original in certain cases.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, I tried your way to simulate and it is approved to sucess injecting more FDs, thanks.